# How to use typescript jsdoc annotations for React PropTypes

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

When defining react components using typescript we can write something like:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<PropInterface, StateInterface> {
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way do the equivalent using [jsdoc annotations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript) and have props type-checked.

Comment: Have you used React's builtin `PropTypes`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Typescript has recently added type checking support through jsdoc annotations. Refer the link in the question.

Comment: @AndrewLi That is being deprecated. And I would prefer the checks to happen at compile time.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I intend to write .js files, which will not have generics and instead have jsdoc comments.

Comment: It is, since when? Have you tried [`@property`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-property.html)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I prefer following form (es2015 + [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react)):

```js
/**
 * @typedef {object} Props
 * @prop {string} className
 * @prop {number} numberProp
 *
 * @extends {Component<Props>}
 */
export default class SomeComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}>
                {this.props.numberProp}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: This makes my IDE very angry. I get spam such as `Method componentDidCatch from interface React.ComponentLifecycle is not implemented`

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is searching for an alternate solution.
Regarding to this [Typescript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15251) you can also achieve it like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/**
 * @augments {Component<{onSubmit:function, text:string}>}
 * @param {object} event - Input event
 * @return {React.ReactElement} - React component
*/
class Test extends Component {
  handleInput = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    const { text } = this.props;
    return <div>Hello, property :O {text}</div>;
  }
}

Test.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Run-time `PropTypes` checks mixed up with static `typescript` checks. I would drop `PropTypes` since it does not make sense to use both.

Answer (score 4):

This works, though it may not be so good.

```
// Foo.jsx
import * as React from 'react';

/**
 * @type {{ new(props: any): {
     props: { a: string, b: number },
     state: any,
     context: any,
     refs: any,
     render: any,
     setState: any,
     forceUpdate: any
   } }}
 */
const Foo = class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className={this.props.a}>{this.props.b}</div>;
  }
};
export default Foo;

// import Foo and use it in .tsx or .jsx file
import Foo from './Foo';

<Foo/>; // error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; b: number; }'
<Foo a='a' b={0}/>; // OK
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works. Can you also suggest how to flag passing unspecified props as errors?

eg. in your example if I call something like: `<Foo a='a' b={0} c={20}/>`, I don't get any errors.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I get an error `Property 'c' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes ...` when I call `<Foo a='a' b={0} c={20}/>` with `"compilerOptions": { "target": "es5", "allowJs": true, "checkJs": true, "jsx": "react" }`. I am using TypeScript 2.3.2.

Comment: I am trying with all files as js files (including the one that imports it), along with `// @ts-check`.  

tsconfig:
`
{
    "compilerOptions": {
 "noEmit": true,
 "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "React",
        "checkJs": true,
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "include": [
 "./src/"
    ]
}
`

Comment: Actually when both files are js the type validations are not happening at all.

Comment: I created [a repo on github](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-jsdoc-support-react), in which type checking is working as expected in (probably) the same condition as yours.

Comment: OK. I was not assigning to const Foo and exporting that. This is weird, but works. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PropTypes,

something like this works for me:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/**
 * Test component
 * @augments {Component<Props, State>}
 */
class Test extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

Test.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default class Test1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Test  />
  }
}
```

[image: vscode proptypes intellisense]

Comment: how did you define Props and State?