# JSDoc (better-docs) not showing required propType correctly

Tags: reactjs, documentation, jsdoc, react-proptypes, jsdoc3

Using the better-docs plugin for JSDocs with a React app. It is meant to parse the proptypes and take the information from PropTypes and put them into an array. It does. But shows Required as 'No' in the table even when the propType is marked with isRequired.

https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs#usage-2

https://softwarebrothers.github.io/admin-bro-dev/index.html

**Example component**

```
/**
 * Some documented component
 *
 * @component
 * @example
 * const text = 'some example text'
 * return (
 *   <Documented text={text} />
 * )
 * @category Dumb component
 */

const Documented = (props) => {
    const { text } = props
    return (
        <div>{text}</div>
    )
}

Documented.propTypes = {
    /**
     * Text is a text
     */
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default Documented
```

**JSDoc Config**

```
{
  "tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc"]
  },
  "source": {
    "include": ["src"],
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
    "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "plugins/markdown",
    "node_modules/better-docs/component",
    "node_modules/better-docs/category"
  ],
  "templates": {
    "better-docs": {
      "name": "My React components"
    }
  },
  "opts": {
    "destination": "docs",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "recurse": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "readme": "README.md",
    "template": "node_modules/better-docs/"
  }
}
```

[image]

Alternately looking for a JSDoc plugin that parses comments for proptypes and also indicates the required props for a component.

Thanks!

Comment: facing same issue. awaiting any helpful answer for better-docs

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your IDE doesn't support [react-styleguidist](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/documenting/#limitations) properly. Fortunately, there is another solution for documenting react component as example below.

```
import React from 'react';

/**
 * @typedef {object} Props
 * @prop {number} numberProp - A numeric example, this is required.
 * @prop {string} [className] - Optional, you can ignore this.
 *
 * @extends {React.Component<Props>}
 */
export default class SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    // Instead of undefined,
    // className will be an empty string when not defined
    const className = this.props.className || "";
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        {this.props.numberProp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Source: [How to use typescript jsdoc annotations for React PropTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768915/how-to-use-typescript-jsdoc-annotations-for-react-proptypes)